# Validar se método existe no webservice e customizar mensagem de retorno

Tags: java, web-service

Estou criando um webservice rest, e está funcionando adequadamente, porém há uma situação que não consegui tratar: caso a url fornecida esteja buscando por um método inexistente, o solicitante é redirecionado para a tela de erro do meu sistema, sendo que eu gostaria de exibir uma mensagem customizada. Segue descrição:

url1 (válida): https://127.0.0.1/sistema/ws/exemplo/consulta1?param1=teste1&param2=teste2

url (inválida): https://127.0.0.1/sistema/ws/exemplo/consulta2

Gostaria que ao receber uma url diferente de url1, o sistema exibisse uma mensagem customizada, ao invés de redirecionar para a tela de página não encontrada. Porém como devo criar um método para interceptar e validar a url, sendo que o path informado não existe em minha classe?

```
@Path("/ws/exemplo")
public class exemploResource {

    //único método implementado atualmente
    @GET()
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("consulta1")
    public String consulta1(@QueryParam("param1") final String param1,
            @QueryParam("param2") final String param2,
            final @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
   ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma dica de tratamento (infelizmente perdi o link da referência) e adaptei para meu uso, criando o seguinte método:

```
@GET()
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("{url}")
public String validaServico (@PathParam("url") final String url) {
    //metodosExistentes é uma lista com todos os métodos existentes
    if (this.metodosExistentes.contains(url))
        return "";
    else
    {
        //omiti parte do código de setar mensagem e criar xml de retorno 
        //por não ser pertinente ao assunto
        erro.setDeErro("Consulta desejada não encontrada.");
        return XmlUtil.objectToXml(erro);
    }
}
```

Veja que a primeira condição apenas existe para manter a estrutura do método de validação, pois se a url informada for válida(ou seja, existir método), o método correto será chamado e meu método de validação não será disparado.